# How to reduce MSSQL Logfile size?

Tags: arcgis-10.0, arcgis-server, enterprise-geodatabase, sql-server, arcgis-9.3

First of all I am not a Database specialist. I am using MSSQL to store my SDE 9.3 Data which is served with AGS 10.0. I have Vector and raster data stored in the databases and have very little room left on my SQL Server because the logfiles are just very big. One Database which contains 314GB of Data has a logfile which has a size of 28GB!

What can I do (if anything) to reduce the size of this logfile?

Comment: This isn't really a GIS question. A google on "truncate transaction log" will  give you what you need, database wise.  Modern best practice is to manage rasters i.n mosaic datasets in imagery formats on the filesystem.